# reshape long format to wide format by ""COUNT".. How can I make it?

Tags: r

I'm a R beginner

I have a dataframe as following below

[image]

I want reshape dataframe above like this .. by "Dataframe format"

[image]

I know i can make it by 'table function' 
table(incomegr=edu.q$incomegr,edu.q$langgr)
but this format is 'table' not 'dataframe'

ie, i want make each 'incomegr', 'Gr9', 'Gr8' 
as dataframe columns.

How can I make it?

Comment: What would be the value column in the expected output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(incomegr=edu.q$incomegr,edu.q$langgr))
```